# Ad finished loading,but banner is not shown (AdMob banner)

Tags: android, admob, banner

tried few different methods,including Listeners/Creating Linear Layout,but banner is not shown at all (tried also with test device and emulator).
anyone has a solution for this ??

this is the MainActivity code:

```
MainActivity.java
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity   {

        private GoogleApiClient client;
        private AdView adView;

        @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
            getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();
            super.onBackPressed();
            int count = getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();
            if (count == 0) {
                super.onBackPressed();
            }
            }

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            MobileAds.initialize(this, "pub-6338964718220230");
            AdView adView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
            adView.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-6338964718220230/1764788102");
            adView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
            adView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAdLoaded() {
                    Log.d("Ad", "onAdLoaded: ");
                }

                @Override
                public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
                    super.onAdFailedToLoad(errorCode);
                }
            });
            AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice("E1CDC038C238379BFAB16A576EC21D17").build();
            adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

this is the fragment_main xml code:

fragment_main.xml

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-6338964718220230/1764788102"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

this is the activity_main xml code:

activity_main.xml

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

Comment: Which AdView are you using? means of activity_main or fragment_main?

Comment: Is your onAdFailedToLoad got fired? if then what is the error code

Comment: it's not stopping on the onFailedToLoad,it stops on the onAdLoaded.

Answer (score 0):

try to change size of ad display to a fixed one to see if the problem is the adSize, i got a similar problem too and was SMART_BANNER the problem

Comment: even when i changed to AdSize.BANNER,problem still occures.

Comment: 05-15 13:56:12.103 11572-11572/? I/Ads: Starting ad request.
05-15 13:56:13.199 11572-11572/? I/Ads: Scheduling ad refresh 60000 milliseconds from now.
05-15 13:56:13.241 11572-11572/? I/Ads: Ad finished loading.

but still,nothing appears